# ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: using CAST

Tags: casting, db2, sas

I am trying to use some SQL code in SAS within a proc SQL. The original code in DB2 had this which is working fine.
 I get the below syntax error at as

```
541         as NC_2,SUM (  CASE WHEN A.R_1='N'    AND A.R_2='N'    AND A.R_4='Y' then 1   else 0
541      ! end ) as NC_4   FROM (  SELECT CASE    WHEN (LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(cast(ABC_CT  as char(4000)), '
             __
                                                                                            22
                                                                                            202
541      !           ',
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, (, ), *, **, +, ',', -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, 
              BETWEEN, CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, IS, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, 
              ~, ~=.  

ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAST is a conversion/type function - i.e. put in this format. In SAS translate is to replace occurrences of letters so not the same category of functions.

I think you're looking for the PUT function that will convert a numeric to character, assuming ABC_CT is numeric.

```
put(ABC_CT, 4000.)
```

Or you can use SQL PASS THROUGH which will run the DB2 code directly on the DB2 server and uses DB2 syntax. 
Example of the type of syntax from the documentation:

```
proc sql;
 connect to db2 as db1 (database=sample);
 select *
  from connection to db1
     (select
* from sasdemo.customers
         where
 customer like '1%');
disconnect from db1;
quit;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001348730.htm

Answer (score 0):

Cast function is not present in sas. This may be a issue if you are accesing a db2 table directly from sas.

Comment: This is accurate, but it seems like you could give the original poster some information as to how to perform that same operation in SAS, no?

Comment: i removed cast and tried a translate, that is throwing an error saying translate needs to have a character expression. i have to run this SQL using SAS on DB2. i have no other option , is there any other option i can use?